# $\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\sqrt{(z+1)/(z-1)}}{z-3}\,\mathrm{d}z$ over different circles

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show there is exactly one analytic branch $f$ of $\sqrt{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}$ on $\mathbb{C}-[-1,1]$ which is negative on $\{z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}:y=0,x>1\}$. Find the first three terms of the Laurent series of $f$ on $\mathbb{C}-\overline{B(0,1)}$. Then calculate $\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-3}\,\mathrm{d}z$ for the different circles $\Gamma=C(0,R)^+, R=2,4$.

I managed to solve the first two parts. The Möbius transformation $M(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ maps $\mathbb{C}-[-1,1]$ one-to-one onto $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$, so we could just take the principal branch of the square root; the only other branch is than the negative of this branch, which indeed satisfies the given conditions. So with $\sqrt{\cdot}$ denoting this principal branch, $f(z)=-\sqrt{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}$.

Then writing $w=\frac1z$ we could calculate the Laurent series at infinity of $-\sqrt{\frac{1+w}{1-w}}$, which, by the extended binomial theorem, and then using a geometric series for $w$ on $B(0,1)$, simplifies to $$-\left[1+w+\frac{w^2}2+\frac{w^3}2+\cdots\right]=-\left[1+\frac1z+\frac1{2z^2}+\frac1{2z^3}+\cdots\right].$$

I thaught about ways to calculate the integrals that are asked about, but didn't get any further. I did not find a way to show that the integral on $C(0,R)^+$ converges as $R\to\infty$, so that using the Residue theorem with a residue at infinity did not work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have a power series in $1/z$ that $f$ is equal to on these circles. You also know exactly how those circles can be expressed as a curve of parameter $t$. You can easily manually calculate what the integrals of each of the terms must look like, and even integrate them (yes there are some regularity concerns about exchanging integral and infinite sum, but they can be handled in this case).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I figured out another way already, by substituting $w=1/z$ and taking the residue at $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere